# What's the most efficient way (best performance and least gc) to store unique sorted values in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

what's the most efficient way (best performance and least gc)  to store unique sorted values in Java?

Currently I use a HashMap to get a collection of unique values then I copy the HashMap values into a ArrayList then use Collections.sort() to sort the values as my objects implement Comparable which finally gives me a unique sorted values. The code will be run thousands of times a second so I want the best approach. Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

/The code will only be run in a single thread.

My code is below:

```
public class LapRanking {
    private final Map<String, Car> carsInRace = new HashMap<String,Car>();

    public List<Car> processLap(Car car){

        carsInRace.put(car.driverName, car);

        List<Car> lapTimeRankings = new ArrayList<Car>(carsInRace.values());

        Collections.sort(lapTimeRankings);

        return lapTimeRankings;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car one = new Car("DriverOne");
        Car two = new Car("DriverTwo");
        Car three = new Car("DriverThree");

        LapRanking lapRanking = new LapRanking();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            one = one.setLapTime();
            two = two.setLapTime();
            three = three.setLapTime();

            lapRanking.processLap(one);
            lapRanking.processLap(two);
            lapRanking.processLap(three);
        }
    }
}

public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private static final Random randomTestTimes = new Random();
    public final String driverName;
    public final double lapTime;
    public final double firstQuarterTime;

    public Car(String driverName) {
        this.driverName = driverName;
        this.lapTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        this.firstQuarterTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public Car(String driverName, double lapTime, double firstQuarterTime) {
        this.driverName = driverName;
        this.lapTime = lapTime;
        this.firstQuarterTime = firstQuarterTime;
    }

    public Car setLapTime(){
        return new Car(driverName,randomTestTimes.nextDouble(), randomTestTimes.nextDouble());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        int i = Double.compare(lapTime, o.lapTime);
        if(i !=0)
            return i;

        return Double.compare(firstQuarterTime, o.firstQuarterTime);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Car {driverName='").append(driverName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", lapTime=").append(lapTime);
        sb.append(", firstQuarterTime=").append(firstQuarterTime).append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to show Car as immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't timed it or done any benchmarking, but I strongly suspect that you'll get the biggest speedup by eliminating the "new" allocation of the ArrayList in processLap.  Memory allocations are far more expensive than a sort on a 3 item list.

If you haven't added any cars between successive calls to processLap, then there's really no need to copy the values from the HashMap into an allocated ArrayList over again.  Just sort the ArrayList you already had.

```
public class LapRanking {
    private final Map<String, Car> carsInRace = new HashMap<String,Car>();
    ArrayList<Car> lapTimeRankings;

    public List<Car> processLap(Car car){

        Car oldcar = carsInRace.put(car.driverName, car);

        if (oldcar == null)
        {
            lapTimeRankings = new ArrayList<Car>(carsInRace.values());
        }

        Collections.sort(lapTimeRankings);

        return lapTimeRankings;
    }
```

And as someone else has already said - the need for the hash table is suspicious as well.

If you can have a separate function for inserting cars into the race rather overloading processLap, then you'll be even better....

```
public class LapRanking {
    private final Map<String, Car> carsInRace = new HashMap<String,Car>();
    boolean isDirty;
    ArrayList<Car> lapTimeRankings;

    void insertCarIntoRace(Car car)
    {
        carsInRace.put(car.driverName, car);
        isDirty = true;
    }

    public List<Car> processLap(Car car){

        if (isDirty)
        {
            lapTimeRankings = new ArrayList<Car>(carsInRace.values());
            isDirty = false;
        }

        Collections.sort(lapTimeRankings);

        return lapTimeRankings;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car one = new Car("DriverOne");
        Car two = new Car("DriverTwo");
        Car three = new Car("DriverThree");


        LapRanking lapRanking = new LapRanking();
        lapRanking.insertCarIntoRace(car1);
        lapRanking.insertCarIntoRace(car2);
        lapRanking.insertCarIntoRace(car3);


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            one.setLapTime();
            two.setLapTime();
            three.setLapTime();

            lapRanking.processLap(one);
            lapRanking.processLap(two);
            lapRanking.processLap(three);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, for the application as written, the map actually serves no useful purpose.  IMO, the most performant solution would be to replace the map with an `Car[]` of the appropriate size pre-allocated and populated on startup.  Then do an in-place sort of the cars once each lap using `Arrays.sort()`.

This satisfies your requirement.  It is storing unique objects (the `Car` objects) and keeping them sorted.

There *should be* no garbage generated after startup, apart (possibly) for garbage created by the `sort(...)` method itself ... and in outputting the rankings.

Something like this:

```
    Car[] cars = new Car[] {one, two, three};

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        one.setLapTime();
        two.setLapTime();
        three.setLapTime();

        // Sort the cars based on their `compareTo` method; i.e. lap time.
        Arrays.sort(cars);

        // Output the cars, ranked by lap time
        for (Car car in cars) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Updated for the variant where the Car is immutable:

```
    Car[] cars = new Car[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        one = one.setLapTime();
        two = two.setLapTime();
        three = three.setLapTime();
        cars[0] = one;
        cars[1] = two;
        cars[2] = three;
        Arrays.sort(cars);
    }
```

Or ... more concisely:

```
    Car[] cars = new Car[]{one, two, three};
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cars.length[]; j++) {
           cars[j] = cars[j].setLapTime();
        }
        Arrays.sort(cars);
    }
```

(Though I must say that a `setter` that actually creates and returns a new object is pretty poor interface design.  If I was code reviewing that code, there would be a LOT of red writing all over it ...)

---

By the way, the idea of using a `TreeMap` doesn't help, because your algorithm is actually sorting the map's value set not the key set.

Comment: "By the way, the idea of using a TreeMap doesn't help, because your algorithm is actually sorting the map's value set not the key set." It depends how OP defines the values, let me say that again. What if he keeps two TreeMaps?! What if he redesigns a bit?

Comment: If the program's requirements were different, then TreeMaps might help. But this Question is about a specific problem as set by the OP. Other (hypothetical) problems are (IMO) out of scope.

Comment: @kdgregory - The OP's original code does not bear this out.  And even if it did need a map, the ranking process is best (i.e. most efficiently) handled *independently* of the map, irrespective of what kind of map you use.

Comment: @kdgregory - By the way, selbie's answer also agrees that the map is "suspicious" ...

Comment: I am saying that the `main` represents the problem we have been asked to solve.  Whether it is realistic or not is irrelevant.  If the OP's *real* problem is substantively different, he should tell it what is.  In the mean time, we should solve the problem as given rather than trying to hypothesise alternative problems, that he might-or-might-not actually mean.

Comment: @kdgregory - You can see what good asking the OP for clarity has done; i.e. none.  I prefer to answer questions *my way* ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about using `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

They might be a good fit for your case.

Comment: TreeMap/TreeSet do unique based on the compare which isn't what i want thanks. So from my example if 2 cars have the same time only 1 car will exist in the TreeMap.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends how you define your keys. And your values too.

Comment: More importantly, the program is sorting the value set not the key set.  So changing to a TreeMap won't make any difference.  It certainly won't eliminate the need to do the sorting ... and the associated copying to a new collection that has to happen.

Comment: @StephenC Stephen, this is a pretty negative comment on a pretty positive idea. The fact that OP's classes/structures are not perfectly designed does not make the TreeSet/TreeMap idea irrelevant here.

Comment: @peter.petrov - This is only a positive idea if it helps.  If you examine what the OP is doing here, you will see that it doesn't help.  For a different problem, maybe it would help.  But that's not what this Question is about.

Comment: @StephenC OK, apparently it's a waste of time. I will leave this answer here for now just in case OP finds it useful. I understood that you don't, no need to repeat that 3-4 times IMHO.

Comment: Well I did find the need to address your comments, so that's why I did it. If you hadn't responded in a way that suggested that you didn't "get it", then I wouldn't have felt the need to explain it ... again.